# Mapping obj-c object to sqlite database

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, mapping

Im looking for a simple (if I can call it that) mapping tool for obj-c, that maps objects and their relationships to a sqlite database. Is there any out there that acts like db4o for java? I havent found anything on google, and I think its because Im not completly sure of where to look and what to look for.
Hope someone can help, because I dont want to write my own mapping tool to sqlite.

**EDIT**
it seems like entropyDb does the job. http://code.google.com/p/entropydb/. But Im not sure yet.

I dont quite understand this line: "One cannot store instances of Cocoa classes directly. Collections (NSArray, NSSet, NSDictionary) can be stored if they are instance variables of custom objects." I read it like I cant store arrays and sets if they are instance variables of a custom object.

Comment: EntropyDB is licensed under the GPL. This means that you can't include it without also open sourcing your app. Not sure if this is a problem for you?

Comment: Oh thats might gonna be a problem for some of my apps. But not all.

Comment: Im going to use the entropydb. That looks like the right for me:) But thanks for the Core Data hint Graham Lee!!

Comment: EntropyDB 1.2 (the iOS version) is licensed under LGPL. But it doesn't appear to be very active.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html), which is part of the iPhone SDK.

Comment: Oh. Im new to iPhone development :) Im not at all into it yet. Dont know what that is.

Comment: @mslot: well the link is to the "Introduction to Core Data", which _may_ tell you what it is...

Comment: I must say that I dont get it :)

Comment: Um, Core Data stores Objective C objects in a SQLite database. It's included in both OS X and iPhone OS 3.

Comment: Stephen, that I do get. But how is it done. I cant figure it out from that link.

Comment: @mslot: there are Core Data tutorials on Apple's web site.